# Issues writing HTML form fields to text file

Tags: php, html, file, text, output

I'm trying to write the contents of a HTML form field to a text file on my web server.

I was able to get code I found on an example to work in a plain PHP file, but not in my desired file.

Whenever I submit the form, PHP throws an error. `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: person in <snip>/upload.php on line 26, referer: <snip>/upload`

Here's the code of the file I want to log:

```
<?php

//Delete Current Files
$dirfiles = glob('<snip>/uploads/*'); // get all file names
foreach($dirfiles as $dirfile){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($dirfile))
    unlink($dirfile); // delete file
}

//Upload New Files
foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "uploads/" .     $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
    }
}

echo "<h2>Successfully Uploaded Images</h2>";

//Log
$when = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$who = $_POST["person"];
$out = fopen("output.txt", "a");
if (!$out) {
print("Could not append to file");
exit;
}
fputs($out,"$who\t");
fputs($out,"$when\t");
fputs($out,"$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]\n");
print("Name, Time, Date, and IP Address have been recorded.");

?>
```

In the log file, date and IP address are logged fine, but not the name. (Like This)

`February 11, 2013, 3:26 am  IPADDR`

where the name should be at the beginning like

`JohnDoe    February 11, 2013, 3:26 am  IPADDR`

In the original form file, it's just a typical form:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php">
<input type="text" name="person" /> Your Name<br />
snip...
</form>
```

The only difference between the form where the logging worked and where it didn't was that this one also allows for image uploading via `<input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple />`

What on earth would be causing the name not to be logged?

Edit: Update - It turns out thus bug is not present in Internet Explorer, but still is present in Chrome and Firefox. That's really strange.

Comment: What do you see as the output when you replace each fputs call with a similar print call?

Comment: And what to you see when you print_r($_POST);

Comment: @turiyag On the page, when I swapped the fputs with print, I got the following printed; `February 11, 2013, 3:50 am 24.168.247.250 Name, Time, Date, and IP Address have been recorded.` all on the same line in the same font, etc.

Comment: @turiyag Only thing different from my above comment when I added print_r($_POST); is `Array ( )` after "recorded."

Comment: Try `print_r(array_keys($_POST));`

Comment: this is not possible, there must be another file or some code that you not posted in the question.

Comment: @Stefan Still just an added `Array ( )`

Comment: If it happens only on one browser it sounds like something is happening before you post $_POST["person"]; . Are you using js or something that could be different between browsers?

Comment: Yes, but what is in the array? Is 'person' a key in the array that is shown?

Comment: @CosLu You are correct. Should have mentioned that I am using JS as a part of this webpage which uploads image files with JS/JQuery. JS file is at [link](http://pastebin.com/nRSgdYHq)

Comment: @Stefan All that is shown is exactly what I have posted. That, and nothing more. Nothing is inside the array.

Comment: The js file prevents default form submission. it might send the arguments as serialize or any, via ajax.

Comment: If it helps, here is a [LINK](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) to the original tutorial

Comment: You don't have `enctype="multipart/form-data" `

Comment: @Stefan I took that out trying to fix it. Image uploads still work fine, just not the text field with it in there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add formdata.append("person", $('input[name=person]').val()); in your js file

```
if (formdata) {
    formdata.append("person", $('input[name=person]').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res; 
        }
    });
}
```

REF
[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: And we have a winner! That was it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Disregard my comment that was here. Works fine in Firefox. Cache was still there. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You must set enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html form attributes.  I suspect FormData.append() isn't working properly if you don't.

EDIT:

Try adding this to the javascript code (maybe after `if (formdata) {`):

```
var person = $('input[name=person]').val();
formdata.append('person', person);
```

Comment: As I said in the comments, I took that line out trying to fix it. However, image uploads work fine with our without it. Same goes for the text field - it doesn't work with it or without it.

Comment: Got me (in the log file) `undefined February 11, 2013, 4:21 am MYIP`